# ctags not found : pthread_mutex_init

Tags: vim, ctags

I have installed omnicppcomplete, taglist, cscope, etc., and I generated my tags in `/usr/include` using:

```
ctags -R --c++-kinds=+plx --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .
```

And in my `.vimrc` I set:

```
set tags=/usr/include/tags,./tags,./..tags,./**/tags
```

But now when I write my multi-thread programs, I can not switch to `pthread_create` and `pthread_mutex_init` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. It says "tags not found".

So I am writing here for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should look in your tags file to determine if `pthread_mutex_init` and `pthread_create` are actually in them. If they are not then it is likely that either (1) the source wasn't scanned or (2) they don't actually exist in the form you expect. Both `pthread_create` and `pthread_mutex_init` are contained in `libc`, which is a very complex set of code, and often you will find that a symbol is defined in a indirect way through multiple layers of pre-processor macros, in which case ctags won't work.

Comment: i searched the tags file in /usr/include, finding the following line
__pthread_mutex_init bits/libc-lock.h  /*extern int __pthread_mutex_init(.........)*/

it is just like what you said. and pthread.h indeed includes many pre-processor macros.
so is there any method to let ctags know these tags?

PS, i notice that when i typing and pressing ctrl+n to do word completion, it can successfully parse the pthread_create and pthread_mutex_init function

Comment: Good question. What is in your file: `/usr/include/pthread.h`. On my Mac the full `pthread_create` declaration is there, so ostensibly this would all work here. Check `pthread.h` for `pthread_create`. If it is in there like you expect, then I think that the file isn't getting parsed.

Comment: i have checked the /usr/include/pthread.h, i also have the full pthread_create declaration there in my Fedora 13. but i notice another problem, it can parse pthread_join, but can not pasrse pthread_create. so i am sure the file is parsed but it seems that it doesn't parse all of them, do i need some other configuration?

Comment: Hrmm...Exubertant ctags won't extract pthread_create on my mac either. I'll look at this a little more tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this SO post which will probably solve your problem:

[ctags ignore lists for libc6, libstdc++ and boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626188/ctags-ignore-lists-for-libc6-libstdc-and-boost)

Answer (score 0):

Please test as follows because ctags need some micros to generate

sudo ctags  -I **THROW  -I __THROWNL -I __attribute_pure** -I **nonnull -I __attribute** -R --c-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C  /usr/include/

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea but,i get the right way to (ctrl+]) jump the function(pthred_create,pthred_mutex_init),just add some parameters into ctags,like(@TerryZJ), but his command maybe is not enough,you can use this:

**sudo ctags -I THROW -I __THROW  -I __THROWNL -I __nonnull -I __attribute_pure -I nonnull -I __attribute -R --c-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C /usr/include/**

by the way if you cannot jump to the right function,you can search if some tags is behind the declaration for example ：

```
extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
               const pthread_attr_t *__restrict __attr,
               void *(*__start_routine) (void *),
               void *__restrict __arg) *__THROWNL* *__nonnull* ((1, 3));
```

if so,you maybe cannot jump,just add "-I __THROWNL" when you use ctags.
hope useful to all.

Comment: Formatting is bad