# ctags ignore lists for libc6, libstdc++ and boost

Tags: c++, c, linux, vim, ctags

I use ctags with vim and the [OmniCppComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520) plugin.  Currently when generating my tags I do it individually for each library.  For libc6 I use the following list of tokens / macros in a file named libc6-ignore to ignore during processing:

```
__attribute__
__attribute_deprecated__
__attribute_format_arg__
__attribute_format_strfmon__
__attribute_malloc__
__attribute_noinline__
__attribute_pure__
__attribute_used__
__attribute_warn_unused_result__
__wur
__THROW
__nonnull+
```

Am I missing any other tokens I should be ignoring and should I be using this same list or a different one when generating tags for libstdc++ and boost?

For anyone who's interested I use the following to generate my tag files:

```
# First make sure apt-file is install and then do:

$ sudo apt-file update

# set up tags for libc, the standard C library

$ apt-file list libc6-dev | grep -o '/usr/include/.*\.h'> ~/.vim/tags/libc6-filelist
$ ctags --sort=foldcase --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -I./libc6-ignore -f ~/.vim/tags/libc6 -L ~/.vim/tags/libc6-filelist 

# create tags for stdlibc++ and STL

$ apt-file list libstdc++6-4.4-dev | grep -E -o '/usr/include/.*\.(h|hpp)' > ~/.vim/tags/stdlibcpp-filelist
$ ctags --sort=foldcase -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f ~/.vim/tags/stdlibcpp -L ~/.vim/tags/stdlibcpp-filelist

# For Boost

$ apt-file list boost | grep -E -o '/usr/include/.*\.(h|hpp)' | grep -v '/usr/include/boost/typeof/' > ~/.vim/tags/boost-filelist
$ ctags --sort=foldcase --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f ~/.vim/tags/boost -L ~/.vim/tags/boost-filelist
```

Comment: I'm pondering the question, but meanwhile, wouldn't `dpkg -L` be quicker than `apt-file list`?

Comment: @Phil Lello: Don't know, don't think it's relevant and anyways sounds like premature optimization ;-)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can also use the modified libstdc++ library:</strike>

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2358

This contains a stripped version of the C++ header files which works for ctags.

I made a Python script that extracts all tags beginning with an underscore from a tags file. You can choose with this script which tags to exclude.
Feel free to tailor the script to meet your needs or suggest anything else:

```
import re

tags=open('tags','r')
output=open('exclude','w')
regex=re.compile('^_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*')
results=set()

for line in tags:
    result=regex.match(line)
    if(result!=None):
        results.add(result.group(0))

tags.close()

for element in sorted(results):
    output.write('{0}\n'.format(element))

output.close()
```

Comment: I looked at that and the thing is I'm not sure that it's necessary.  So far the tags file I've generated *seems* to be doing the job.

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes: Hope my answer is better now.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed those instructions and I am able to get all boost boost references working i.e.

```
#include <iostream>
```

I can jump directly to iostream

However what I am  still missing is to go to for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Although in my generate script I have included as you mentioned i.e.

```
$ apt-file list libc6-dev | grep -o '/usr/include/.*\.h'> ~/.vim/tags/libc6-filelist
$ ctags --sort=foldcase --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -I./libc6-ignore -f ~/.vim/tags/libc6 -L ~/.vim/tags/libc6-filelist
```

After i generate the tag "libc6" file whenever I try to go to stdio.h it is saying “E426: tag not found: stdlib”.

Here is what I have included additionally to my .vimrc in order to make all those 3 tag files visible.

```
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/boost
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/libc6
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/stdlibcpp
```

I am not an expert however I can say that this worked somehow for boost but not for libc6-dev. Can someone assist me with the solution

here is the same code as above

sudo apt-file update

```
# set up tags for libc, the standard C library

apt-file list libc6-dev | grep -o '/usr/include/.*\.h'> ~/.vim/tags/libc6-filelist
ctags --sort=foldcase --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -I./libc6-ignore -f ~/.vim/tags/libc6 -L ~/.vim/tags/libc6-filelist

apt-file list libstdc++6-4.6-dev | grep -E -o '/usr/include/.*\.(h|hpp)' >> ~/.vim/tags/stdlibcpp-filelist
ctags --sort=foldcase -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f ~/.vim/tags/stdlibcpp -L ~/.vim/tags/stdlibcpp-filelist

# For Boost
apt-file list boost | grep -E -o '/usr/include/.*\.(h|hpp)' | grep -v '/usr/include/boost/typeof/' > ~/.vim/tags/boost-filelist
ctags --sort=foldcase --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f ~/.vim/tags/boost -L ~/.vim/tags/boost-filelist
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry--I've never used ctags before--but I'll take a stab at this question.

If I understand correctly, you can use the list of keywords from GCC itself. I found this https://gist.github.com/959484 inside `gcc/gcc/c-family/c-common.c`. Looks like it includes reserved words for all the C (c/c++/obj-c variants). I guess some are valid for all compilers, these are for gcc of course.

As for figuring out other symbols to ignore, on OS X I'd use nm to dump the symbols of the library in question an add all symbols marked as private ('s' instead of 'S' for example) to my list of symbols to ignore. Linux has a similar library-dumping tool?

Hope that's useful.

Comment: Linux has `nm` too.  Also `objdump`.

Comment: OS X uses the same GNU binutils that we use on Linux, which includes `nm`, `objdump`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had my own list and never thought about adding what you've already listed!

Here's that updated ignore list for libc6 that I've come up with (Ubuntu 14.04 and GCC 4.8.4) to use as input to the -I option of ctags:

```
__attribute__
__attribute_deprecated__
__attribute_format_arg__+
__attribute_format_strfmon__+
__attribute_malloc__
__attribute_noinline__
__attribute_pure__
__attribute_used__
__attribute_warn_unused_result__
__attribute_alloc_size__+
__attribute_const__
__attribute_artificial__
__wur
__THROW
__THROWNL
__BEGIN_DECLS
__END_DECLS
__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
__END_NAMESPACE_STD
__USING_NAMESPACE_STD+
__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_C99
__END_NAMESPACE_C99
__USING_NAMESPACE_C99+
__warndecl+
__warnattr+
__errordecl+
__flexarr=[]
__fortify_function
__REDICRECT+
__REDIRECT_NTH+
__REDIRECT_NTHNL+
__ASMNAME+
__ASMNAME2+
__nonnull+
__always_inline
__extern_inline=extern
__extern_always_inline=extern
__extension__
__restrict
__restrict_arr
```

I also created the following ignore list for generating a tags file for libstdc++ (GCC 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04) (again, this is input to the -I option):

```
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_VERSION
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_ALGO
_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_ALGO
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_CONTAINER
_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_CONTAINER
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_EXTERN_C
_GLIBCXX_END_EXTERN_C
_GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY+
_GLIBCXX_PURE
_GLIBCXX_CONST
_GLIBCXX_NORETURN
_GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR=constexpr
_GLIBCXX_USE_CONSTEXPR=constexpr
_GLIBCXX_THROW_OR_ABORT+
_GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
_GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
_GLIBCXX_THROW+
_GLIBCXX_NOTHROW
```

I changed `__attribute__` to be: `__attribute__+` to indicate it looks like a function and should be ignored.

Of course, I have created one for Boost as well, but I think I'll refrain from posting it until someone has a need.